# How to hide simple Checkbutton from screen when using selectimage in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

I'm making a GUI application in which I want to use checkboxes (`Checkbutton` in Tkinter). I'd don't really like the design of the simple check-buttons (and I don't want to use ttk) so I decided to use images from the internet. I have a selected.png and a deselected.png. When assigning them to my Checkbutton they appear, but the original simple checkbox doesn't disappear.

*Here is a Screenshot from the window, so you can get a better understanding of what I'm talking about.*

[image]

```
...
deselect_image = PhotoImage(file='deselected.png')
select_image = PhotoImage(file='selected.png')

classic = Checkbutton(window, font = ('Courier', 10), image = deselect_image, text = " Classic theme", selectimage = select_image, compound = 'left', variable = theme_classic, bg = "#FFFFFF", command = lambda: select_theme("classic"))
classic.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "w")

blue = Checkbutton(window, font = ('Courier', 10), image = deselect_image, text = " Dark Blue theme", selectimage = select_image, compound = 'left', variable = theme_blue, bg = "#FFFFFF", command = lambda: select_theme("blue"))
blue.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "w")

black = Checkbutton(window, font = ('Courier', 10), image = deselect_image, text = " Black theme", selectimage = select_image, compound = 'left', variable = theme_black, bg = "#FFFFFF", command = lambda: select_theme("black"))
black.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = "w")
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can hide the check-button box by passing the argument `indicatoron=False` but this will give you a *raised/sunken* effect when unchecked and checked respectively. If you don't want that *raised/sunken* effect then change the value of *borderwith to 0*.

*Something like this*

```py
Checkbutton(window, font = ('Courier', 10), image = deselect_image, 
            text = " Classic theme", selectimage = select_image, 
            compound = 'left', variable = theme_classic, bg = "#FFFFFF", 
            command = lambda: select_theme("classic"), 
            indicatoron=False, borderwidth=0)
```

[See all the options for a `Checkbutton`.](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method)